# Как можно финансово благодарить участников?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

В жизни существует принцип обмена. На работе, компетентно выполняяя свои обязанности, ты отдаёшь работодателю своё время и энергию — он платит тебе зарплату. В дружбе ты помогаешь своему другу в одной ситуации, в другой ситуации он помогает тебе. В браке муж финансово обеспечивает жену — она заботится о нём, поддерживает дом в чистоте, воспитывает детей.

Когда один человек получает что‑то от другого, ничего не отдавая взамен или отдавая недостаточно, в конечном итоге он начинает чувствовать себя некомфортно. В такую ситуацию могут попадать пользователи этого сообщества, и в неё попал я. На протяжении года, регулярно заходя сюда задавать свои вопросы, я получаю ответы примерно от одних и тех же участников. Причём ответы эти развёрнутые и видно, что люди вкладывают своё время и энергию, а также прикладывают свои знания и компетентность. Со своей стороны, не будучи экспертом в русском языке, я не могу компетентно и полно отвечать на большинство вопросов на сайте, да и времени нету. Таким образом, в рамках тематики сайта я не могу ничего дать участникам, которые качественно отвечают на мои вопросы. Но я могу поблагодарить их финансово. На мой взгляд, это будет честным поддержанием равноценного обмена для меня и подобных мне участников этого сайта, которые по большей части лишь задают вопросы.

**Вопрос**

Существует ли на сайтах сети Stack Exchange практика финансового вознаграждения участников? Если да, то в каком формате? Встроенные модули или, может быть, пользователи с высоким рейтингом в описании своих профилей указывают свой "Яндекс Кошелёк"?

Answer (score 4):

Участники этого форума скорее всего **не заинтересованы в финансовом поощрении**, у каждого есть своя мотивация для работы здесь.

Лично для меня этот форум является чем-то вроде **клуба по интересам,** а интерес, конечно же, к русскому языку. Я не люблю праздных разговоров, а здесь практически все общение сводится к конкретным темам. И в то же время получаешь возможность **изучить характер людей,** прогнозировать их поведение, просто наблюдать за ними, это тоже достаточно интересно.

**Безусловно, собственный уровень знания языка повышается**, когда практически ежедневно решаешь нестандартные задачи  практического характера. Причем решаешь их по своему желанию, выбираешь то, что нравится, а это важно, так как чувствуешь себя свободным от любых обязанностей, а такую свободу за деньги не получишь.

**Чем автор вопроса может отблагодарить участника?** Для меня это корректное, доброжелательное и вежливое отношение.

**Вам ответили на вопрос?** Вы можете поставить галочку "ответ полезен" или принять ответ, если он удовлетворил вас. Можете переспросить, уточнить что-то, сказать спасибо — по крайней мере, отвечающий будет знать, что вы его ответ прочитали и благодарны ему даже в том случае, если он вашей проблемы не решил.

Людям, которые ведут себя вежливо и достойно, хочется отвечать, **их приятно видеть на форуме, как хороших друзей.** Других же я стараюсь **обходить стороной**, отвечаю на их вопросы редко, только если уж действительно вопрос проблемный и интересный, да и отвечаю скорее не для них, а для других потенциальных читателей.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, на сайтах сети Stack Exchange предусмотрено лишь вознаграждение очками репутации: если вы благодарны, проголосуйте за ответ и поставьте «галочку». Участники, делающие большие успехи, могут получать некоторые поощрения от компании.  Более того, иногда проводятся конкурсы с вполне материальными наградами.

Comment: А  за какие успехи и какие поощрения можно получить от компании?

Comment: @Sharon по достижении высокого рейтинга (100000, например) :) Поощрения — сюрприз!

Comment: На исполнение одного желания можно договориться?  Какого - сюрприз.